# How to make a diagram like this in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, diagrams

Does anybody know how to make this type of diagram in `LaTeX` with arrows and notations? (Example diagram is from `Wikipedia`).

[image]

Comment: where did you get that image,  isn't the source available?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number#/media/File:Stirling_numbers_as_polynomial_basis_change.svg

Comment: The image is clearly made using the `xy` package (the arrow heads are very distinctive). I'd probably recommend using the `tikz-cd` package. There is also the `commutative-diagrams` which I;ve never used.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419221/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272268/diagram-for-limit for some starting points

Comment: Of course the code is provided https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stirling_numbers_as_polynomial_basis_change.svg

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why yes, s__C's link includes the tex/`\xymatrix` source for that svg.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Direct link to the latex source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stirling_numbers_as_polynomial_basis_change.svg#LaTeX.2FTikZ_source_code

Comment: @s__C sorry, I missed that

Comment: @s__C do you want to post a "get the sorce from wikipedia" answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done for sake of completeness!

Comment: @s__C thanks....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

% based on \binom
\newcommand{\stirlingi}[2]{\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\stirlingii}[2]{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tstirlingi}[2]{\genfrac[]{0pt}{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tstirlingii}[2]{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=8em,column sep=4em]
& x^n \arrow[dl,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']
      \arrow[dr,"\tstirlingii{n}{k}"']
\\
x^{(n)} \arrow[ur,"\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']
        \arrow[rr,"{L(n,k)}"]
&&
(x)_{n} \arrow[ul,bend right=20,"(-1)^{n-k}\tstirlingi{n}{k}"']
        \arrow[ll,bend left=15,"{(-1)^{n-k}L(n,k)}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid large labels like in the picture you show.

The braces in the labels with `L(n,k)` are necessary in order to avoid Ti*k*Z mistaking the comma for something that separates options.

Comment: Thank you very much. Best regards.

Comment: @Miskolin If you satisfy with the suggestion, then please accept it by clicking the`tick` mark

Comment: I accepted it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Miskolin, no, you didn't ...

Comment: I voted for the question instead of accepting it. :) But now I did.

Answer (score 1):

With `xy`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix@C+2.5em@R+2.5em{
    &
    x^n
        \ar[ddr]_*{\begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}}
        \ar@/_15pt/[ddl]_*{(-1)^{n-k}\begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}}  
    & \\
    &  & \\
    x^{(n)}
        \ar[rr]^*{L(n,k)}
        \ar[uur]_*{\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}}
    & &
    (x)_{n}
        \ar@/^15pt/[ll]^*{(-1)^{n-k}L(n,k)}
        \ar@/_15pt/[uul]_*{(-1)^{n-k}\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}}
}
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 as noted in comments under the question this is the source made available by arxiv https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stirling_numbers_as_polynomial_basis_change.svg#LaTeX.2FTikZ_source_code

Comment: Where "arxiv" probably means "the Wikimedia project". ;)